# How do I run Test Flight app or .ipa file on mac

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, testflight

I have a React Native App that I built in Expo. I can run this successfully using a simulator. However, I want to upload this project to TestFlight to share with other users. The only problem is I personally do not own an iPhone, to now test the app in TestFlight. Is there any way, I can re-run the TestFlight app, the .ipa file, or this new version of the app on my mac? Apple is going to make me buy an phone aren't they. Blaaaargh!

Answer (score 0):

iOS apps are compiled for an ARM cpu. An Apple Silicon Mac has the possibility to run iOS apps natively.

Comment: Hmmm Any tips here? I don't understand